# Автоматически добавлять завершающий слеш в уже работающем htaccess файле

Tags: php, .htaccess

Появилась необходимость добавлять финишный слеш в url в уже используемом микро-mvc. Вот блок из текущего .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону правил:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Более подробно [тут](https://techjourney.net/add-trailing-slash-to-the-end-of-the-url-with-htaccess-rewrite-rules/) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781331/4772782)

Comment: Помогло добавление этих двух строк перед последним правилом.